# invalidselector exception + selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have been hit with InvalidSelectorException on a regular basis when i run my selenium web driver test script

My test fails with this InvalidSelector Exception and throws message as :

> The xpath expression '//form[@name=somelocator]' cannot be evaluated or does not result in a WebElement

The element locator i use is perfect which return a correct web element when i cross verify it using xpath checker / or with browser console, so no issue with the element locator

I click on some button and then wait for the above xpath locator element to load in the application UI and giving enough `waitTilllElementVisible()` methods before checking the above locator

I found that many faced this issue, but could not get the concrete reason for this failure.

Selenium asks to visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html for the documentation on this error, but this link looks not up

Reproduced it with selenium 2.45 and 2.46 version with IE11

Please let me know if you knows  the reason for this and why it throws invalidSelector exception on browser open with webdriver

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `SPACE` character in the `@name` tag. Try `"//form[@name='some locator']"` or `'//form[@name=\'some locator\']'`.

Answer (score 0):

@peetya's answer is probably correct and a better answer but I prefer CSS Selectors... they are less error prone if you have the option to not use XPath.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form[name='some locator']"));
```

[CSS Selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

Comment: I am sorry, In the original element locator, there is no space in the value of the name attribute..Yes , css selector seems to be working good in this situation ..i just change this xpath to css, haven't observed the issue so far..